# Is there any non-constant polynomial satisfying $f(1) = f(2) = 0$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

*Before the question, I clarify that by "polynomial", I mean any function in the form of

$f(x) = \sum c_ix^i$.

I am wondering whether there exist a polynomial which is not constant (so that it has some x with non-zero factor) but satisfies

$ f(1) = f(2) = 0 $

I intuitively think there is no such polynomial but have no clue how to prove that.

Comment: according to given condition $2$ and $1$ are zero of poynomial that means $(x-2)$ and $(x-1)$ are its factor ,just multiply them and that will be your answer

Comment: That sounds right. Then can we say that any polynomials which satisfy the condition has (x-2) and (x-1) as its factor?

Comment: polynomial are continous fnction so if they are zero at some point $a$ then $(x-a)$ is factor of that polynomila

Answer (score 8):

What about $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$?

Answer (score 1):

José's answer is perfect. But because you asked in the comments, let me perhaps say a bit more.

> If a polynomial $p(x)$ has a root $a$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$

*Proof.*  We can long divide polynomials. So long divide $p(x)$ by $x-a$, and hence write $p(x)= (x-a)q(x) + r(x)$ for some polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$. Now this equality holds for any value of $x$. But evaluating at $x=a$, we find $p(a)=0= 0+r(x)=r(x)$. Hence, $r(x)=0$. But then $p(x)= (x-a)q(x)$, i.e. $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$.

So if you want a polynomial with roots $x=1,2$, then $x-1$ and $x-2$ will both be factors of the polynomial. So your polynomial must be of the form $(x-1)(x-2)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. To find one of the simplest possible examples, take $q(x)=1$, then
$$
(x-1)(x-2)= x^2-3x+2,
$$
as in José's beautifully simple answer. Of course, there are infinitely many examples:
$$
\begin{split}
(x-1)(x-2)x&= x^3-3x^2+2x \\
(x-1)(x-2)(x-1)&= x^3-4x^2+5x-2 \\
(x-1)(x-2)(x^2+1)&= x^4-3x^3+3x^2-3x+2 \\
\end{split}
$$
Generally, if you want a polynomial with (for simplicity, let's say distinct roots) $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, then 
$$
p(x)= (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)q(x),
$$
will work, where $q(x)$ is any polynomial. Note that $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ may not be all the roots because, depending on your choice of $q(x)$, $q(x)$ (and hence $p(x)$) may have roots. As a final note, if you wanted these to be *all* the roots, e.g. in the example above, you had better choose $q(x)$ to be a polynomial with no real roots, as in my last example above.

Comment: It's worth specifying that this is only true if $1.$, the ring from which the coefficients come from contains $a$ (every polynomial with coefficients from a field has a root in some extension field), and $2.$, the ring of coefficients is a UFD.